# Mapbox throw error on click event that Map Container is already Initialized...So How can I reinitialized the map

Tags: php, jquery, mapbox

```
// Here Is The Div With MAp Id    
<div id="map" ></div>
```

// These Are Onclick Event Of Javascript Through Which Map Changes
    Pencil
                        high contrast
                        Wheat Paste

```
    <script>
//That is function which is called through javascript Onclick Event
            function myMapStyle(style,id){

            L.mapbox.accessToken ='pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FkZGFtMjIxIiwiYSI6ImNpdjB0cnF6NTAwMzAyem1rMmhhOHdib2YifQ.Q7Z7bH77Mdf2W8k78O7ilQ';
                        var map = L.mapbox.map('map',id,{
                            center : [31.450112, 74.308888],
                            zoom: 13,
                        });


                        L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.'+style,{
                            attribution: 'Map Data',
                            maxZoom:18,
                        }).addTo(map);
                    };
     </script>
```

Comment: its a simple matter of reading the documentation properly

Comment: i searched it a lot and used these code but still not working